# Problems on combination of binary sequences

Tags: combinations, coding-theory

Show that we cannot find 171 binary sequences (sequences of 0’s and 1’s), each of length 12 such that any two of them differ in at least four positions.

I assume $S$ to be any set of binary sequences of length 12 any two of them differ in at least four positions. I was just told that the answer could be found from   $|S|((12C0)+(12C1)+\frac16 12C2))≤$ $2^{12 }$. But I don't know how to get this inequality.

Comment: The questions seems to be entirely in the first paragraph... and the second paragraphs looks as it were the start of an attemped proof? Or what?

Comment: You (probably) need to take some minutes to understand the proof of the Hamming bound 
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1641589/understanding-the-hamming-bound
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_bound